# Display two columns as one

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-4.2

I wanted to select two columns and display it as one in my controller. Here is the code I currently have:

```
public function assignment()
{
    $title = "View Parent Assignment";
    $vpc   = DB::table('dbo_guardianchild')
                ->join('dbo_students', 'dbo_guardianchild.StudentID', '=' , 'dbo_students.StudentID')
                ->join('dbo_guardianinformation' , 'dbo_guardianchild.GuardianInformationID' , '=' , 'dbo_guardianinformation.GuardianInformationID')
                ->select('dbo_students.StudentID' , 'dbo_students.FirstName AS sFname' , 'dbo_students.LastName AS sLname')
                ->get();
}
```

Any ideas on how I can combine the `dbo_students.FirstName` and `dbo_students.LastName` into one column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try DB::raw. Try replacing the code in select as

```
    ->select(DB::raw('dbo_students.StudentID' ,'CONCAT(dbo_students.FirstName, " ", dbo_students.LastName) AS full_name'))
```

And your final code will be

```
public function assignment()
{
    $title = "View Parent Assignment";
    $vpc   = DB::table('dbo_guardianchild')
                ->join('dbo_students', 'dbo_guardianchild.StudentID', '=' , 'dbo_students.StudentID')
                ->join('dbo_guardianinformation' , 'dbo_guardianchild.GuardianInformationID' , '=' , 'dbo_guardianinformation.GuardianInformationID')
                ->select(DB::raw('dbo_students.StudentID' ,'CONCAT(dbo_students.FirstName, " ", dbo_students.LastName) AS full_name'))
                ->get();
}
```